# Expressjs failing to detect response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I'm trying to get my nodeapp working using express.

I've setup a reverse proxy via nginx to use https://dank.ml/api/v1 but whenever I start up my app, it doesn't want to detect the **/** response.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var def = {'details': 'Running API v1.0'};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Home');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('API is now running on: 127.0.0.1:8080');
```

Here is my config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/dank.ml/;

        server_name dank.ml;

        location /api/v1 {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s clearly saying

> Cannot GET /api/v1

i.e. the path passed to express is **/api/v1**.

Use this config:

```
    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

i.e. trailing slashes in both `location` and `proxy_pass`.
[source](https://serverfault.com/questions/444532/reverse-proxy-remove-subdirectory)

Comment: Oh I thought it would work no matter what. Anyway thank you for your help. :>